# Check the presence of files within directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, os.walk

under "mypath" i have one folder and under this folder i have files and i want to check the existance of files under this folder, but in my example below it checks only the directory where is the folder (where there is no files) , So any idea?

```
for root, dirname , file in os.walk(mypath)):
    if not file:
        raise Exception("there is no file")
```

Comment: You are exiting the for loop the first time you find an empty directory, which is the root, rather than the branch you want to check. You need to add a check that `dirname!==mypath` if statement.

Comment: if root != mypath , i think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the right directory:

```
for root, dirname , file in os.walk('c:\\myfolder', topdown=False):
    if root != 'c:\\myfolder' and not file:
        raise Exception("there is no file")
    elif root != 'c:\\myfolder':
        break
```

Like @tdelaney's answer, does not check if there are multiple subdirectories

Comment: Why did you add the topdown=False parameter  ?

Comment: Makes `os.walk` start at the bottom, which will be the directory you are interested in, if it is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` is a convenience function and you are free to try other methods.

```
from glob import glob
import os
has_files = len(glob(os.path.join(mypath, '*', '*'))) > 0
```

This is a little loosy because its not strictly checking for a single subdirectory, but may be sufficient for your use case.